# rename multiple files with unique name

Tags: mac-osx, rename

I have a tab-delimited list of hundreds of names in the following format

```
old_name    new_name
apple       orange
yellow      blue
```

All of my files have unique names and end with *.txt extension and these are in the same directory. I want to write a script that will rename the files by reading my list. So apple.txt should be renamed as orange.txt. I have searched around but I couldn't find a quick way to do this.I can change one file at a time with 'rename' or using perl "perl -p -i -e ’s///g’ *.txt", and few files with sed, but I don't know how I can use my list as input and write a shell script to make the changes for all files in a directory. I don't want to write hundreds of rename command for all files in a shell script. Any suggestions will be most welcome!

Comment: The `shell` tag tells us nothing. What operating system. Are those files all in the same directory? What scripting language do you want this in? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks John for your suggestions, I have edited my question to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

This should work as it's fairly standard bash

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
    do
        set -- $line
        echo renaming "$1.txt to $2".txt
        mv "$1".txt "$2.txt"

    done <input.file
```